# C# binary tree data structure with static root node

Tags: c#, data-structures, tree, binary-tree

I tried creating a data structure for a static binary tree with a static root value and 2 child nodes. I am trying to make it dynamic for any number of child values. How can I do that with a static root node. How can I implement if I take myArray = {3,11,8,18,21,36,1}. Any simple code with out complex code changes would help.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode();
        rootNode.value = 9;

        int[] myArray = { 3, 11 };

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.Length; i++)
        {
            if (myArray[i] > rootNode.value)
            {
                //add to right node
                TreeNode right = new TreeNode();
                right.value = myArray[i];
                rootNode.rightNode = right;

            }
            else
            {
                //add to left node
                TreeNode left = new TreeNode();
                left.value = myArray[i];
                rootNode.leftNode = left;
            }
        }
    }
}

class TreeNode
{
    public int value { get; set; }
    public TreeNode leftNode { get; set; }
    public TreeNode rightNode { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: What kind of binary tree do you want?

Comment: a full binary tree

Comment: Full binary tree have only one condition that all nodes have 0 or 2 child. It means that it's not matter what values will have descendant child nodes of current node, but you post this `if (myArray[i] > rootNode.value)`. So are you sure that you want full binary tree but full search binary tree?

Comment: Yes I am looking for that

Comment: well, it's very easy way: **1**: create two child nodes for current node; **2**: then set current node by the left child node from step 1; **3**: repeat step 1 until `array.Legth > 1`; As you can see you will retrive a full binary tree that all nodes have 0 or 2 child. You only need little change a loop in your code and add the last element to current node after the loop

Answer (score 1):

Hey this code is running is fine but you can improve it further if you want. Sorry but i had to make a bit lengthy. Hope you understand the code. Its not difficult. The code is in java by the way. Just change the syntax into c# .

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Scanner a = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number of childs!");
        int input = a.nextInt();
        TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode();
        TreeNode parent = rootNode;
        rootNode.value = 9;

        parent.childNodes = new TreeNode[input];
        for(int i = 0; i< input; i++){
            parent.childNodes[i] = new TreeNode();
            parent.childNodes[i].value = 0;
        }
        parent.hasChild = true;
        int count = 1;
        int startingIndex = 0;
        int EndingIndex = input - 1;
        int next = 0;

        int[] myArray = { 19, 11, 12, 13 ,14, 15 };

        for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++)
        {
            if(count <= input){
                if (myArray[i] > parent.value)
                {
                    //add to right node
                    parent.childNodes[EndingIndex].value = myArray[i];
                    EndingIndex--;
                    count++;
                }

                else
                {
                    //add to the left node
                    parent.childNodes[startingIndex].value = myArray[i];

                    startingIndex++;
                    count++;
                }
            }
            else{
                parent = parent.childNodes[next];
                parent.childNodes = new TreeNode[input];
                for(int j = 0; j< input; j++){
                    parent.childNodes[j] = new TreeNode();
                    parent.childNodes[j].value = 0;
                }
                parent.hasChild = true;
                next++;
                count = 1;
                i--;
                startingIndex = 0;
                EndingIndex = input - 1;
                next = 0;
            }

        }

        parent = rootNode;
        TreeNode grandparent = parent;
        System.out.println("root Node: " + parent.value);
        next = 0;
        int childs = 1;
        while(parent.hasChild == true){
            for(int i=0; i<input; i++){

                if(parent.childNodes[i].value != 0){
                    System.out.print("child " + childs + " : ");
                    childs++;
                    System.out.print(parent.childNodes[i].value);
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }
            childs = 1;
            System.out.println();
            parent = grandparent.childNodes[next];
            next++;
        }
    }
}

class TreeNode
{
    public int value;
    TreeNode[] childNodes;
    boolean hasChild = false;

}
```